# How to test node heroku tasks in local environment

Tags: node.js, heroku

How do I test a heroku node task on my local machine using the heroku runtime environment (foreman?)

I can successfully run my task like so: `node my_task.js`. Now I need to (a) make it an executable in the `bin` directory, which will make it dependent on the location of the node binary on the system, and (b) I need this specific task to use environment variables defined in my .env file, which I can't mimic by just running it with node unless I hard code them, but that would defeat the purpose.

Is there a way to use foreman or heroku cli to run a task as it would be run in the heroku environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with Heroku support and figured this out. I didn't realize you can use foreman to run other processes:

`foreman run node bin/my_task` works for me. That way I can also keep the shebang node path as `app/bin/node` instead of having to switch it to `usr/bin/node` for my Ubuntu box.